# Como mostrar en un ListBox el resultado de una consulta SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, .net, vb

recien me cree una cuenta en esta fabulosa pagina porque realmente estoy desesperado de que no me salga algo tan sencillo como es esto. Estoy recien iniciando con Visual Studio VB.net.
En definitiva lo que estoy haciendo es un pequeño programa conectado a una base de datos la cual pueda consultar,agregar, modificar productos.
Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que un boton tome valores escritos en un textBox y a partir de ella realice una consulta sql y que esta me muestre todas las filas encontradas en un list box que tengo preparado. pero no me sale.. desde ayer que vengo intentando y buscando por todos lados y NADA ya estoy desesperado jaja.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento para el boton que deberia realizar lo anteriormente explicado:

```
    Private Sub BotonValidar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotonValidar.Click
    TextCant.Hide()
    Cantidad.Hide()
    TextCosto.Hide()
    Costo.Hide()
    TextPrecio.Hide()
    Precio.Hide()
    BotonConfirmarAgregar.Hide()
    BotonConfirmarAcumular.Hide()
    Dim userModel As New UserModel()
    Using connection = GetConnection()
        connection.Open()
        Using command = New SqlCommand()
            Dim rd As SqlDataReader
            command.Connection = connection
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextCodigoBarra.Text) Then
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextDescripcion.Text) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Debe rellenar al menos el campo 'Codigo' o 'Descripcion'")
                Else

                    command.CommandText = "select * FROM Producto WHERE descripcion LIKE '%'+@desc+'%'"
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", TextDescripcion.Text)
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                End If
            Else
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextDescripcion.Text) Then

                    command.CommandText = "select * FROM Producto WHERE codigo LIKE '%'+@cod+'%'"
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", TextCodigoBarra.Text)
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Else

                    command.CommandText = "select * FROM Producto WHERE descripcion LIKE '%'+@desc+'%' AND codigo LIKE '%'+@cod+'%'"
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", TextDescripcion.Text)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", TextCodigoBarra.Text)
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                End If
            End If
            rd = command.ExecuteReader()
            If rd.HasRows Then
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                ListBox1.Items.Add(rd)
                rd.Dispose()
                BotonConfirmarAcumular.Show()
            Else
                rd.Dispose()
                BotonConfirmarAgregar.Show()
            End If




        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Bueno paso a explicar masomenos el codigo porque esta medio feo a primera vista
La busqueda se puede hacer por codigo, por descripción o por codigo y descripcion **(Esto depende de que TextBox rellene el usuario)** esto explica el porque realizo tres consultas SQL en IF anidados..
A lo ultimo estoy intentando mostrar el resultado obtenido y nada.. si alguien me ayuda estaria eternamente agradecido ! Saludos

Comment: Hola Axel. Supongo que has validado que "rd" tiene valores?

Comment: Hola si, con el debugger me fije y el RD en hasrows me aparece true.. no se si es suficiente eso.. la consulta la ejecuto en SQL Management Studio y si me funciona

Comment: Haber si con algo así te puedes guiar. La idea del While es recorrer lo que hay en el rd y cada elemento del rd agregarlo al list, ya según te convenga fila o cada col
If rd.HasRows Then
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                While rd.Read()
                ListBox1.Items.Add(rd["Columna1"].ToString + " " + rd["Columna2"].ToString + " " + rd["Columna3"].ToString )
            End While
                rd.Dispose()
                BotonConfirmarAcumular.Show()
            Else
                rd.Dispose()
                BotonConfirmarAgregar.Show()
            End If

Comment: Max, gracias por la respuesta pero me tira errores de compilacion en la linea del ListBox1.Items.Add(....).
los errores son:
- Caracter no valido (Tres veces sale este error)
- Se esperaba un identificador (Tres veces sale este error)

Answer (score 0):

Si me permites sugerirte creo que sería mas sencillo y presentable mostrar el contenido de una consulta en un datagridview, mas o menos asi sería el código, ya nadamas le agregarias los if's para validar que el campo no este en blanco.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Dim adaptador As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dv As New DataView
    Public con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.conexion)
Private Sub BotonValidar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotonValidar.Click
    con.Open()
                adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Producto WHERE descripcion="& TextDescripcion.Text, con)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                adaptador.Fill(ds)
                dv.Table = ds.Tables(0)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
                DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
                con.Close()

End Sub
```